# str replace acts funny when does not receive right number of arguments

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
"ahoj".replace("o")
//=> "ahundefinedj"
"ahoj".replace("q")
//=> "ahoj"
```

Why is that? How is replace implemented? Is there any way I could see the implementation itself?

Comment: You need to tell it what to replace it with. You get undefined back in your string.

Comment: You really answered your own question in the title of your question: Q: "str replace acts funny when does not receive right number of arguments. Why?" A: Because it doesn't receive right number of arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay attention to what you get.

```
ah undefined j
```

Spaces added for emphasis. It replaced `o` with the second argument... which was `undefined`.

The second replace does nothing because there is no `q` to replace.